# Creating "dir" command using CreateProcess function failed with error code 2

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I was just playing with Win32-API and wanted to create a process using `CreateProcess` function. I used the following code from MSDN website:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

But surprisingly I can't create a `dir` process using this piece of code. Error code indicated that **'The system cannot find the file specified.'**
I'm using Visual studio 2015 and Windows 7 64Bit. But when I run the same executable in Windows 10, everything is OK.

Comment: "Dir" is not an executable process.  It is merely a command that the command processor (cmd.exe) understands.  There are others, like echo and copy.  Not something you have to fix of course, you don't need CreateProcess() to enumerate files in a directory.  But if you can't resist then use `cmd.exe /c command`.

Comment: dir process? Is that the name of an executable file? Are you trying to list directories using dir command? If yes then you will have to use ::system("dir") to do so.

Comment: Question is off-topic ?!

Comment: On a side note, we don't need `ZeroMemory()` in C++. Just write `STARTUPINFO si{sizeof(si)};` which sets `cbSize` member and zero-initializes all remaining members and write `PROCESS_INFORMATION pi{};` to zero-initialize all members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dir` is not an external command that can be run.  It's a command internal to the Windows Command Prompt.  You'll need to call your program as `myprogram "cmd /c dir"` to do that.

Of course, there are better ways to iterate a directory than calling an external program, but that's a separate question.

Comment: But I can run this program successfully in Windows 10 and I can list all files using `dir` command. Let me test your advice. Thanks.

Comment: @saeed but when you test it manually, you are testing it within a `cmd.exe` process. `dir` is not its own executable that you can run directly, you have to use `cmd.exe` instead. But like others side, this is not the best way to enumerate a directory. Use `FindFirstFile/Ex()` and `FindNextFile()` instead.

Comment: Better than hardcoding the name of the command processor would be `myprogram "\"%comspec%\" /c dir"`.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of going through 1500 lines of C code, it finally dawned on me what my problem was and why it worked on one Windows 10 system of mine but not on another.  The system that it worked on, I really did have a  DIR.EXE.  But is was not the COMSPEC DIR that was running.  I had DIR.EXEs in Git and MinGW folders.

Read this for how to correctly use CREATEPROCESS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa